# Where on the SE network do questions go about choosing a new programming language?

Tags: discussion

I recently witnessed the following question get moved from SO to programmers.SE, and subsequently closed, picking up downvotes along the way:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/121892/i-am-having-a-hard-time-learning-python-is-it-just-me

This is unfortunate, since many, **many** beginners are bound to have similar questions. How are people supposed to get started programming or pick a language if they don't have a way to get advice from the community?

Where do these questions go?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right now there is no Stack Exchange sites that would accept questions like that.

IMHO, it's probably for the better. The choice of language really doesn't matter in 99% of the cases. Although if there were specific requirements at play, choosing a language that fit them would be on-topic at [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), but those questions are rather rare.

Other sites like Reddit and Quora are more tolerant of questions like this, so they may be better places to ask.

Further reading:

- [Is there really a choice of the best language for a specific project?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99113/is-there-really-a-choice-of-the-best-language-for-a-specific-project)
- [Why is "what language should I learn" considered off-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1573/why-is-what-language-should-i-learn-considered-off-topic)

Comment: It would just help if either someone wrote one canonical blog post about it or we had one question that explains this and the rest can be closed as a dupe of that.

Answer (score 4):

Nowhere on the Stack Exchange network; these types of questions are purely subjective and have no definitive answers.  They're not the kind of questions we want asked here.

<sub>Ok, [chat](http://s.tk/chat) would be a safe place to take it but that's about it.</sub>